# Carousel arriba de un menú con Position Fixed (Bootstrap)

Tags: css, html5, bootstrap

Tengo un problema, tengo un carousel de Bootstrap que cuando hago scroll hacia abajo, este se superpone arriba del menú que tengo con `position:fixed;`.
No sé si será que Bootstrap tiene los carousel para que estén enfrente del contenido que se está mostrando o qué, pero es un problema, y necesitaría solucionarlo. La otra que se me había ocurrido es hacer el menú completamente nuevo con BootStrap. Adjunto una imagen de como se ve.

[image: Cómo se ve]

Les adjunto mi código. (El BootStrap que estoy utilizando es el más reciente de todos v5.1.3)

```
<article class="row justify-content-start  align-items-center">
            
            
                        <div class="col text-center">
                            <p class="">DisCor ofrece una amplia variedad de productos. Específicamente con
                                más de 6000 artículos y más
                                de 40
                                rubros, entre los cuales, Cerrajería y Accesorios del Automotor.</p>
            
            
                            <a href="views/rubros.html" class="btnIntro">Nuestros Rubros</a>
                        </div>
            
                        <div class="col">
                            <div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-bs-ride="carousel">
                                <div class="carousel-indicators">
                                  <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-bs-slide-to="0" class="active" aria-current="true" aria-label="Slide 1"></button>
                                  <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-bs-slide-to="1" aria-label="Slide 2"></button>
                                  <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-bs-slide-to="2" aria-label="Slide 3"></button>
                                </div>
                                <div class="carousel-inner">
                                  <div class="carousel-item active">
                                    <img src="imagenes/(Frenos).jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
                                  </div>
                                  
                                </div>
                                <button class="carousel-control-prev" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-bs-slide="prev">
                                  <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                                  <span class="visually-hidden">Previous</span>
                                </button>
                                <button class="carousel-control-next" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-bs-slide="next">
                                  <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                                  <span class="visually-hidden">Next</span>
                                </button>
                              </div>
                        </div>
            
                </article>
```

Comment: Esto me paso a mi en una web y le puse un z-index: -1 al carrousel. Pruebalo a ver si te funciona.

Comment: Está perfecto!!!! Muchas Gracias!! Deja tu respuesta abajo!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ponle un z-index:-1 al carrusel y en un principio se te arreglara.